# How to round up the decimals in javascript..?

Tags: javascript

In following case I want to round up the decimals. Please tell me how to do that. Now I am getting too many decimals. I wanted only 2 decimals...

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="LiveScript">
var a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0;

function grandtotalall(form){
form.weight8mm.value = form.rods8mm.value * 4.482;
form.amount8mm.value = form.weight8mm.value * 47.7;
a = form.weight8mm.value * 47.7;
form.weight10mm.value = form.rods10mm.value * 6.984;
form.amount10mm.value = form.weight10mm.value * 47.7;
b = form.weight10mm.value * 47.7;
form.weight12mm.value = form.rods12mm.value * 10.254;
form.amount12mm.value = form.weight12mm.value * 47.7;
c = form.weight12mm.value * 47.7;
form.weight16mm.value = form.rods16mm.value * 18.234;
form.amount16mm.value = form.weight16mm.value * 47.7;
d = form.weight16mm.value * 47.7;
form.weight20mm.value = form.rods20mm.value * 28.932;
form.amount20mm.value = form.weight20mm.value * 47.7;
e = form.weight20mm.value * 47.7;
form.weight25mm.value = form.rods25mm.value * 45.888;
form.amount25mm.value = form.weight25mm.value * 47.7;   
f = form.weight25mm.value * 47.7;
form.grandamount.value = a + b + c + d + e + f;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Please help me out in this..

Comment: You could simply used `Math.ceil(1.3)`


----------


 -> returns 2

Comment: You can use `Math.round()` see http://jsfiddle.net/njwec7ao/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toFixed(2)`, eg

```
form.grandamount.value = form.grandamount.value.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Hi sir, I just added the your  code in the bottom of my script. I found no change in the output. Can you please help me out where I need to add.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [JavaScript toFixed() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) to round decimal in javascript

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Sir, we don't have predefined value in the code. We want generated output to be in 2 decimals.